# How to change DatePicker Dialog color in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change datePicker Dialog color but I dont know how to do it. I found it about this but not jetpack compose can you help me ? this is my DatePicker Dialog code

```
val context = LocalContext.current

 val year: Int
    val month: Int
    val day: Int
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

 val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
        context,
        { _: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
            onDateChange("$dayOfMonth/${month + 1}/$year", day, month, year)
        }, year, month, day
    )

 CustomInputField(
                isFocused = isInputFocused,
                placeholder = "Your Birty Day ",
                currentValue = state.date,
                onClick = {
                    onPickerStateChange(BirthDayPickerState.BIRTHDAY)
                    datePickerDialog.show()
                })
```

this is my all datepicker dialog code.I didn't share because I don't think all the code is necessary, I just tried to share the necessary codes. Let me explain quickly , I have a customInputField. That customInputField like textfield. DatePicker dialog open when I click customInputField and I choose date for user birth day and display it in customInputField as a user birth day but I want to change this DatePicker Dialog because I dont like it how can I do that ? do you have a suggestion for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a theme overlay in the constructor:

```
val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
    context,
    R.style.ThemeOverlay_MyApp_Dialog,
    { _: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
        mDate.value = "$dayOfMonth/${month + 1}/$year, day, month, year"
    }, year, month, day
)
```

The theme overylay is defined in the styles/themes.xml file. Something like:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.Dialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/red500_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blu500_dark</item> <!-- button text color -->
</style>
```

[image]

You can also use the new **`DatePicker`** in the M3 (starting from `1.1.0-alpha04`)

```
    val datePickerState = rememberDatePickerState(initialSelectedDateMillis = 1578096000000)

    androidx.compose.material3.DatePicker(
        datePickerState = datePickerState,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        colors = DatePickerDefaults.colors(
            titleContentColor = Blue500,
        )
    )

    Text("Selected date timestamp: ${datePickerState.selectedDateMillis ?: "no selection"}")
```

[image]

Comment: I change "@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog  " to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" in first solution and much better. Thank you for answer

Comment: Its not my entire answer, but I think this is going to send me down the right track.

Answer (score 0):

[image]The accent color of the DatePickerDialog can customised by applying a styled Theme to the `themeResId` parameter.
Try this out,

```
<style name="DatePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/your_custom_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_custom_color</item>
</style>
```

And apply this theme as,

```
DatePickerDialog(
   context = context,
   themeResId = R.style.DatePickerTheme
)
```

This would apply `your_custom_color` to the accentColor of Calendar, Date Picker Circle and all the CTAs (including "OK" and "Cancel") leaving the background White.